# PHP: Copy file from site A to site B

Tags: php, file, copy, openbase

I have a server with 30 websites.
Now I want to copy a file from site A to site B.

Code:

```
$sExternPath  = str_replace(strtolower(SITENAME), strtolower($aBoardInfo['name']), CORE_PATH_PRIVATE); 
$sNewLogo     = file_get_contents(CORE_PATH_PRIVATE.'users_upload/company_logos/'.$sFileName);
//Put it in the folder 
file_put_contents($sExternPath.$sFileName, $sNewLogo);
```

Error:

> [20-Mar-2015 10:32:30] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents() [function.file-put-contents]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/SITEB.nl/private/logo.jpg) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/SITEA.nl/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/SITEA.nl/httpdocs/pages/login/script.php on line 1262
>
> [20-Mar-2015 10:32:30] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/vhosts/SITEB.nl/private/logo.jpg) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Bewerking niet toegestaan in /var/www/vhosts/SITEA.nl/httpdocs/pages/login/script.php on line 1262

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/var/www/vhosts/SITEB.nl is outside the tree set in the open_basedir setting -You need to edit your php.ini file and change the open_basedir setting to
'/var/www/vhosts/:/tmp/' rather than '/var/www/vhosts/SITEA.nl/:/tmp/' or unset it by commenting it out, then restart apache.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

> When a script tries to access the filesystem, for example using include, or fopen(), the location of the file is checked. When the file is outside the specified directory-tree, PHP will refuse to access it. All symbolic links are resolved, so it's not possible to avoid this restriction with a symlink. If the file doesn't exist then the symlink couldn't be resolved and the filename is compared to (a resolved) open_basedir .